# Exception while making dockbar hook

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-hook

I tried to customize the default dockbar in liferay.

I can reflect my changes into dockbar. But when I login first time after restarting my server, it is giving me exceptions below:

```
05:09:14,950 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][IncludeTag:253] Current URL / generates exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.dockbar.license_005fwarning_jsp

05:09:14,952 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][IncludeTag:154] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.dockbar.license_005fwarning_jsp
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:130)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
```

These errors continuously repeat recursively and stop after some seconds. It shows some license file is missing.

I can't figure out what's the reason behind it.

I already put license_warning.jsp file with the view.jsp file, still it is firing this exception.

The functionality is working fine for me, just giving loop of exception in the log/console as first time user login.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your License file..

If you have license file for your Liferay Version Handy.

Stop your Liferay Server and in **data** folder of your Liferay Server (**Backup** or Remove) the license folder.

**Place your License file in deploy** folder of your server and restart the Liferay

Comment: I am using liferay 6.1.1 CE version. And before making hook its all working, I saw some source that have licence_warning.jsp file with view.jsp in hook, so i put that file with view.jsp. licence_warning.jsp file contains nothing..

Comment: First while tomcat is running.. Remove that hook folder from webapps make sure it is displaying message on console as hook is undeployed. Then in your hook source Remove licence_warning.jsp and also includes added in any jsps of your hook and try redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

hello follow these steps ....

**1 Unzip a new liferay 6.2 bundle in root folder.

2   Go to /root/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/dockbar

3   Copy all the files from this folder.

4   Then go to your liferay location where problem is present.(in my case it is /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/)

5   Go to /tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/dockbar

6   Paste all the files which were copied from the newly unzipped liferay bundle.

7   Restart the server.**